# I am unable to send email from admin panel for order confirmation in Magento(1.9.1.0) Platform

Tags: magento

I am unable to send email from admin panel for order confirmation and after that i got this error. So please guys tell me, If any one know about this issues.

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.  Please contact the server administrator, root@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.  More information about this error may be available in the server error log.  Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send the mails from your local machine, or is the site already hosted on the live server ? If its local, mails wont go.

If you are on live server, you would have unconfigured mail service. As magento, by default would send mails if your mail server is configured perfectly.